# React gives me error when I update state based on other state "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state based on other state and when state changes it gives me an error

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
const [filterState, setFilterState] = React.useState([{field: "dateFilter", value: {range: "ANY_TIME", start: "", end: ""}}]);
const [chartData, setChartData] = React.useState({successData, failData, categories, data});

const processData = (res) => {
  const data = res.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = new Date(a.date),
    keyB = new Date(b.date);
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  categories = data.map((item) => (new Date(item['date'])).toLocaleDateString());
  successData = data.map((item) => item['success']);
  failData = data.map((item) => item['fail']);

  setChartData({...chartData, successData, failData, categories, data});
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  getLineChartCall().then(processData);//async call to get the data
}, []);    

if (filterState.length){
  if (filterState[0].value.range !== 'ANY_TIME') {
    const start = (new Date(filterState[0].value.start)).toISOString();
    const end = (new Date(filterState[0].value.end)).toISOString();

    const filteredData = chartData.data.filter(item => {
      const itemDate = (new Date(item.date).toISOString());
      return (start <= itemDate && end >= itemDate);
    });

    categories = filteredData.map((item) => (new Date(item['date'])).toLocaleDateString());
    successData = filteredData.map((item) => item['success']);
    failData = filteredData.map((item) => item['fail']);

    const data = chartData.data;
    setChartData({...chartData, successData, failData, categories, data});
  }
}

return (
  // render a component based on successData, failData and categories in chartData.
)
```

below statement in the code is executed when filterState is changed

```
setChartData({...chartData, successData, failData, categories, data});
```

and it is causing the error

Comment: You should only call your `set` hooks in response to some event, not on every render. Try only calling `setChartData` when the component first mounts or in response to an event like a click.

Comment: I also need to update the state when another state "filterState[0].value.range" is updated, which is where I am getting the error. any suggestion on how to handle the situation?

Comment: Use second useEffect and do your calculations inside of the second useEffect function. And never use `set`State inside of function directly. It will render by itself infinity. You know, each render triggered your function. And again, again...

Comment: sorry, dint get you @Mustafa can you pls eloborate

Answer (score 0):

This call to `setChartData` is causing the issue because it is happening on every render. What you want instead is for this to only be re-run when its dependencies change.

```
if (filterState.length){
  if (filterState[0].value.range !== 'ANY_TIME') {
    const start = (new Date(filterState[0].value.start)).toISOString();
    const end = (new Date(filterState[0].value.end)).toISOString();

    const filteredData = chartData.data.filter(item => {
      const itemDate = (new Date(item.date).toISOString());
      return (start <= itemDate && end >= itemDate);
    });

    categories = filteredData.map((item) => (new Date(item['date'])).toLocaleDateString());
    successData = filteredData.map((item) => item['success']);
    failData = filteredData.map((item) => item['fail']);

    const data = chartData.data;
    setChartData({...chartData, successData, failData, categories, data}); <= HERE****
  }
}
```

One alternative is to remove this whole section and add a `useEffect` hook:

```
React.useEffect(() => {

  // do the calculations required for setChartData, then:
  setChartData({ ...chartData, successData, failData, categories, data });

}, [/* array of dependencies, when do you want this to be recalculated? */])
```

Comment: I did something similar to what you say.. but put everything inside the useEffect